# Can't make navbar fixed with sticky position CSS

Tags: html, css, sticky

I've been struggling quite a bit with this issue. I've made a navbar with two dropdowns and animations. What I want to do now, is to make it fixed, whenever one scrolls X pixels (I've sat it to 5px in my code). Basically when you scroll past the content above the navbar, it should be fixed.

I have a nav tag with the entire navbar, on which I've added the CSS (in the attempt to make it sticky):

```
position:sticky;
position:-webkit-sticky;
top:5px;
```

I have read a lot of other posts about the issue, but can't seem to find any of the mentioned issues in my code..

What I have checked for / tried:

- Navbar is not inside the header element
- Overflow not hidden on containing elements
- Changing display:flex; on parent
- Element does not get styling after the animation: animation-fill-mode:none;

I know this can also be done with Javascript, but I really want to make it work by just using CSS.

I would really appreciate any help!

My Code:

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

body {
    margin-bottom:3000px; /*add scrolling to page*/
}

p {
    display: block;
}

.nav-container {
    /*sticky part---------------------*/
    position:sticky;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    top:5px;

    animation-name: navbar-animation;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: none;
    animation-timing-function: ease;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-direction: normal;
    /*WEBKIT*/
    -webkit-animation-name: navbar-animation;
    -webkit-animation-duration:1s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: none;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
}
@keyframes navbar-animation {
    0% {
        transform: translate(0, -60px);
        opacity:1;
    }
    100% {
        transform: translate(0, 0);
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes navbar-animation {
    0% {
        transform: translate(0, -60px);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        transform: translate(0, 0);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

.navbar {
    background-color: #BABABA;
    display:flex;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    height: 55px;
    position:relative;
    flex-wrap:nowrap;
    min-width: 500px;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px #7A7A7A;
    z-index:-2;
    justify-content:center;
}

.navbar-item, .dropdown-menu-item, .dropdown-sub1-menu-item {
    list-style:none;
}

.navbar-item {
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace, Helvetica;
    font-size:17px;
}
.navbar-item a {
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 16px 15px;
}

.navbar-item a:hover {
    color:white;
}
.navbar-item:hover {
    background-color:grey;
}

.dropdown-menu {
    display: none;
    list-style:none;
    position:absolute;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    width: 140px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
    top:56px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px grey;

    animation-name: dropdown-menu-animation;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-duration: 120ms;
    animation-fill-mode: none;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-direction: normal;

    /*Chrome/Safari*/
    -webkit-animation-name: dropdown-menu-animation;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 120ms;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: none;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
}

@keyframes dropdown-menu-animation {
    0% {
        transform: translate(0, -5px);
        opacity: 1;
    }

    100% {
        transform: translate(0, 0);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes dropdown-menu-animation {
    0% {
        transform: translate(0, -5px);
        opacity: 1;
    }

    100% {
        transform: translate(0, 0);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

.dropdown-menu-item {
    display:block;
}

.dropdown-menu-item:hover {
    background-color: grey;
}

.dropdown-menu-item a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left:15px;
}
a, a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:black;
}

#dropdown-toggle-hover:hover .dropdown-menu{
    display:block;
}

.dropdown-sub1-menu {
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    left:139px;
    top: -0px;
    background-color:#f3f3f3;
    width: 158px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px grey;
    z-index: -1;

    animation-name: dropdown-sub1-menu-animation;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-duration: 120ms;
    animation-fill-mode: none;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-direction: normal;
    /*Chrome/Safari*/
    -webkit-animation-name: dropdown-sub1-menu-animation;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 120ms;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: none;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
}

@keyframes dropdown-sub1-menu-animation {
    0% {
        transform: translate(-3px, 0);
        opacity:1;
    }

    100% {
        transform: translate(0, 0);
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes dropdown-sub1-menu-animation {
    0% {
        transform: translate(-3px, 0);
        opacity:1;
    }

    100% {
        transform: translate(0, 0);
        opacity:1;
    }
}

.dropdown-sub1-menu-item {
    display:block;
}

.dropdown-sub1-menu-item:hover {
    background-color:grey;
}
#dropdown-sub1-menu-item1-toggle:hover .dropdown-sub1-menu {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Lund</title>
</head>

<header>
    <div>
        <p>Something here</p>
    </div>
</header>

<body>
    <nav class="nav-container">
        <ul class="navbar">
            <li class="navbar-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="navbar-item" id="dropdown-toggle-hover"><a href="#">Projects <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li class="dropdown-menu-item" id="dropdown-sub1-menu-item1-toggle"><a href="#">Project 1 <i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-sub1-menu">
                            <li class="dropdown-sub1-menu-item"><a href="#">About Project</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown-sub1-menu-item"><a href="#">Source Code</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown-sub1-menu-item"><a href="#">Participants</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown-sub1-menu-item"><a href="#">Other</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown-menu-item"><a href="#">Projekt 2</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-menu-item"><a href="#">Projekt 3</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-menu-item"><a href="#">Projekt 4</a></li>
                </ul></li>
            <li class="navbar-item"><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
            <li class="navbar-item"><a href="#">CV</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

<main>

</main>

</body>
<script src="./scripts/scripts.js"></script>
</html>
```

EDIT: Spelling...

Comment: I would recommend leveraging a library that handles this.  That way, it will render consistently across various browsers and devices.  The more modern CSS methods are not cross browser friendly.

Comment: Can you maybe expand on this? I'm not sure I fully understand, still fairly new to programming. I've used flags to make sure it works across supported browsers for now, but I've removed most of them to make it reader friendly in the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the CSS/HTML you've provided, the issue seems to be this CSS rule:

```
body {
    margin-bottom:3000px; /*add scrolling to page*/
}
```

Replace margin with actual height

```
body {
    height:3000px; /*add scrolling to page*/
}
```

And the `position:sticky` works.

Comment: I didn't even consider this! But you're right, it works like a charm! Thank you! much appreciated!